# Audi A7 - 2016 model without parking assist: is the installation of the module "plug & play"?

Tags: audi, electronics, parking

I have the intention of buying a used Audi A7 Sportback from 2016, without the "parking assist" option.
Since i'm a newbie to this kind of stuff, i was wondering if it's something i can install myself and not go to Audi and spend over 5K€ to do it.

I saw that these modules cost a bit over 200€, but once it is installed, is it "plug & play" or are there some other operations I'll need to do?

Thanks for any input you might have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends, did Audi put the relevant wiring and connector in your car? As you don't seem to have the car yet... It is difficult to guess...

If they did it may well be plug&play, but if not it can be a **real** challenge.

If the wiring is there, then the system may need to be told by computer that it now has that park assist available...

You may be lucky and once plugged in it works as intended...

Comment: Thanks Solar Mike. I'm not really sure of what it's needed for it in order to work properly: First guess are the parking sensors (which are already installed) but I don't know if it's needed to reprogram the software, ECU or anything else. Just by taking a quick look around i found this module and the relative support, but I didn't find anything else.

Comment: Finding the module is one thing, knowing what to do with it is another... Until you have both module and car....

Comment: If it’s installed and serviced by Audi, insurance will cover it. If you do a third party or diy installation not only will you void warranty you’ll also get in to a situation of comprehensive claims being cancelled and In cases of liability clauses lose out on this system being covered.